# Win7 DNS Client not working correctly

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns

I have the strangest problem in my admin life so far that is haunting me for almost more than a year and I can't seem to find a solution for it.

While we work on our network we almost always use our AD DNS server for internal name resolution for accessing different nodes through out the network.
But when I work the DNS Lookups that come from my PC are failing several times during the day. They fail constantly unless I restart the DNS Client. Then everything works fine for a while but after 2-3 hours the problem starts over

For example we have an internal web service on a server called `srv1`. If I try via browser `http://srv1`, I get DNS lookup failed error. The same goes for any other internal DNS name.

Then if I try `ping srv1`, I get `Ping request could not find host srv1. Please check the name and try again.`

Ok I say to myself, let's try accessing with FQDN:

`ping srv1.domain.local`
`Ping request could not find host srv1.netbit.local. Please check the name and try again.`

I restarted the DNS client then the problem is gone for a while. It is like something is interrupting the DNS client service but I am unable to locate it.

Only my workstation has this problem in the entire company.

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Which DNS Servers are listed when you call "ipconfig /all"? Are your Servers still listed? Are not other Servers listed? Can you please call nslookup and enter "srv1 ad-dns-ip" so that nslookup definitely uses your DNS Server. Does this work?

Comment: Yes, `ipconfig /all` lists our internal dns servers. We have 2 DNS servers.
I've recently restarted my dns client and for now it works. Also when I type `nslookup srv1` it lists our dns server. Everything is as it should be now.. maybe I should wait and try this when my dns client goes out again

Comment: And `ipconfig /all` lists _only_ your DNS servers? Have you checked this out using Wireshark/Microsoft Network Monitor etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found the problem a few months ago and I saw this question so I decided to answer it just in case anyone else did the same as I did and then hit his head with similar problems.

The thing is that when in Windows domain environment one must always use only the domain dns servers.
In my setup I've used our DC as the primary DNS server and 4.2.2.2 as the secondary DNS. That caused problems on my PC.

And a few months ago we expanded our corporation so another DNS server needed to be installed.
After I added the other internal DNS server as my secondary DNS i suddenly noticed that I don't have the problem any more.

I guess during the first setup it was only me with manual IP settings. All of the other clients had their IPs configured via DHCP and with only one DNS server. So my PC sometimes made the DNS resolutions from the secondary DNS.